# Deserialize Array of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a following json: need to Deserialize in C#.

```
[
    [{
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99996662139893
    }, {
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99995589256287
    }],    
    [{
        "ElementName": "H2 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99996662139893
    }, {
        "ElementName": "H2 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99995589256287
    }]
]
```

I have write the following code to desirialize it.

```
public  class PointElement
{
    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

var testPointList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PointElement>>(testNewJson);
```

but console shows the error

> Controllers.PointElementRecord' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements
>   a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '[0]', line 1, position 2.

need solution how to deserialize this kind array string as this code runs fine for below array

```
[{
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99996662139893
    }, {
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99995589256287
}]
```

Comment: you should edit your JSON string and remove brackets inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to Serialize the with your JSON you can use like below The below one works for your JSON

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PointElement[]>>(testJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a **list of list PointElement** as your json descible, then the json converter should convert from **List>** instead of **List**:

```
var testPointList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<PointElement>>>(testNewJson)
```

Or incase you want to create a **single list of PointElement** then your json need to brackets [] which has nested array:

```
[
    {
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99996662139893
    }, {
        "ElementName": "H1 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99995589256287
    },    
    {
        "ElementName": "H2 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99996662139893
    }, {
        "ElementName": "H2 ",
        "lat": 51.394319720562514,
        "lng": -109.99995589256287
    }
]
```

and then you can  call

```
var testPointList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PointElement>>(testNewJson);
```